# Any Tutorial on how to create a Vim-like editor?

Tags: vim, text-editor, vi

I've been an avid Vim user, and recently became interested in how it works.

Does anyone know if there's a tutorial that goes over basics of converting a normal text editor to have Vi/m capability? The programming language does not matter; I'm quite an experienced programmer.

I have found the following resources so far:

- [The Craft of Text Editing](http://www.finseth.com/craft/)
- [Implementation of Vi Editor with NCURSES](http://www.scribd.com/doc/53680825/Implementation-of-VI-Editor-With-NCURSES)
- [Vi Editor implemented in Python](http://code.google.com/p/pyvi/)
- [Ruvi: Vi(m) clone in Ruby](http://rubyforge.org/projects/ruvi/)

Comment: Sounds like you answered your own question in your question to me. ;)

Comment: @Almo, =). Yeah, I spent a lot of time trying to find existing simple implementations. Hopefully other people could come up with better tutorials than mine. ;-)

Answer (score 10):

I think first you should know that VI/VIM are actually two parts. One is the visual editor called `vi` and the other on is the one-liner editor called `ed`.

Actually `vi` is called **visual** editor because it's built on top of `ed`(editor). It is the visual part of the ex mode, where you can see and edit your text, that's why it get the name **vi** from **visual**.

The **ex mode** is actually a replication/representation of the editor `ed`. Just fire up `ed` on the terminal and use your default Vi ex commands. The **visual**, **replace** and **insert** modes are used by `vi`. For example there are several commands that are actually doing the same thing, for example:

```
:100 // Go to line 100, ex mode (ed)
100G // Go to line 100, normal mode(vi)

:.,5d // Delete 5 lines, ex mode (ed)
5dd   // Delete 5 lines, normal mode (vi)
```

and so on...

For more information on that I recommended to read the excellent book [Learning the vi and Vim editors](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/059652983X) from O'Reilly:

[image]

Comment: Wow, interesting fact about `vi` and `ed`. Thanks for the recommendation. I believe I have the book. Will have to check my bookshelf. =) Will give it a ready to educate myself more about Vi.

Answer (score 2):

As an experienced Vi user you will know that there are primarily two key aspects that make it a different to other (visual) editors:
- input modes <kbd>Esc</kbd> and <kbd>:</kbd> the common ways of switching between them
- contextual keyboard mapping, where multiple key presses build up a command

I have seen a number of people add a subset of Vi keyboard mappings to an existing editor, and whilst it is possible to get some things mapped sensibly, getting a emulation would probably require fairly extensive replacement of the keyboard handling of an existing editor.

Of course the keyboard mappings are fairly well documented, so it shouldn't be too difficult to implement.

The next thing would be to implement the command mode. It depends which editor you are modifying to implement this, but I would imagine changing focus to either a permanent widget/control at the bottom. Once focus is on that control you can easily handle input and then parse and process the command when return is pressed.

The basic syntax of command mode is inherited from ed/sed editors so you could look up implementations (or papers) on that.

All in all, it isn't a massive job to get a superficial implementation that looks a lot like vi. But doing it really well is another matter.  I'd suggest that you seriously consider just using the excellent Vim ( http://www.vim.org/ ).

Answer (score 2):

As a bit of inspiration, you could maybe take a look at implementations of Vi emulation in various IDEs.

- Visual Studio (F#): https://github.com/jaredpar/VsVim
- MonoDevelop (C#): https://github.com/mono/monodevelop/tree/master/main/src/core/Mono.Texteditor/Mono.TextEditor.Vi
- Eclipse (Java): https://github.com/vrapper/vrapper